# MySQL query with left join and time conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following tables:

```
mysql> select * from room;
+----+----------+
| ID | NAME     |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Room 101 |
|  2 | Room 102 |
|  3 | Room 103 |
+----+----------+


mysql> select * from booking;
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| ROOM_ID | START               | END                 | GUEST          |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
|       1 | 2016-04-01 00:00:00 | 2016-04-30 00:00:00 | Dorian Gray    |
|       1 | 2016-05-03 00:00:00 | 2016-05-20 00:00:00 | Vanessa Ives   |
|       1 | 2016-05-21 00:00:00 | 2016-05-30 00:00:00 | Ethan Chandler |
|       2 | 2016-05-06 00:00:00 | 2016-05-18 00:00:00 | John Clare     |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

For each room I'd like to get additional information about its booking status. If it is booked, I want to show the booking status. If it's not booked it has to show `NULL`.

If I start with a basic query..

```
mysql> select * from room r, booking b where r.id = b.room_id;
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| ID | NAME     | ROOM_ID | START               | END                 | GUEST          |
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
|  1 | Room 101 |       1 | 2016-04-01 00:00:00 | 2016-04-30 00:00:00 | Dorian Gray    |
|  1 | Room 101 |       1 | 2016-05-03 00:00:00 | 2016-05-20 00:00:00 | Vanessa Ives   |
|  1 | Room 101 |       1 | 2016-05-21 00:00:00 | 2016-05-30 00:00:00 | Ethan Chandler |
|  2 | Room 102 |       2 | 2016-05-06 00:00:00 | 2016-05-18 00:00:00 | John Clare     |
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

It works OK, but that's not what I want.. let's see with left join...

```
mysql> select * from room r left join booking b on r.id = b.room_id;
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| ID | NAME     | ROOM_ID | START               | END                 | GUEST          |
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
|  1 | Room 101 |       1 | 2016-04-01 00:00:00 | 2016-04-30 00:00:00 | Dorian Gray    |
|  1 | Room 101 |       1 | 2016-05-03 00:00:00 | 2016-05-20 00:00:00 | Vanessa Ives   |
|  1 | Room 101 |       1 | 2016-05-21 00:00:00 | 2016-05-30 00:00:00 | Ethan Chandler |
|  2 | Room 102 |       2 | 2016-05-06 00:00:00 | 2016-05-18 00:00:00 | John Clare     |
|  3 | Room 103 |    NULL | NULL                | NULL                | NULL           |
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

Still, it shows duplicates... Let's try with more conditions:

```
mysql> select * from room r left join booking b on r.id = b.room_id where b.start<now() and b.end>now();
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
| ID | NAME     | ROOM_ID | START               | END                 | GUEST        |
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
|  1 | Room 101 |       1 | 2016-05-03 00:00:00 | 2016-05-20 00:00:00 | Vanessa Ives |
|  2 | Room 102 |       2 | 2016-05-06 00:00:00 | 2016-05-18 00:00:00 | John Clare   |
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
```

Ok... but wrong, since 'Room 103' is not shown (it's not booked)...

I'd like to get something like this:

```
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
| ID | NAME     | ROOM_ID | START               | END                 | GUEST        |
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
|  1 | Room 101 |       1 | 2016-05-03 00:00:00 | 2016-05-20 00:00:00 | Vanessa Ives |
|  2 | Room 102 |       2 | 2016-05-06 00:00:00 | 2016-05-18 00:00:00 | John Clare   |
|  3 | Room 103 |    NULL | NULL                | NULL                | NULL         |
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a sqlfiddle?

Comment: I just created one :)
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52b53

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont understand why you're using a datetime to store dates... but anyway...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM room r 
  LEFT 
  JOIN booking b 
    ON b.room_id = r.id
   AND CURDATE() BETWEEN b.start AND b.end;
```

Comment: I use datetime because the original problem includes also time... but you are right. That worked! Thanks!  :)

Comment: To make it a bit complicated, what if the names were IDs pointing to another table "user"?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33b2d3/2

Comment: It's just another join

Comment: I used inner join for the table user, is it wrong? You used another left join.

Answer (score 0):

The query below should give you the result you're looking for. **SELECT * FROM room r** will give you every room number and **SELECT * FROM booking b WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN b.start AND b.end** will give you the records that contain today's date within your START and END dates.  Then you will **LEFT JOIN** the main query with the sub-query **ON r.id = b.room_id**.

```
SELECT * FROM room r LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM booking b WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN b.start AND b.end) b ON r.id = b.room_id;
```

Comment: Yeah, that seems to work too :) What would be the advantage of this compared to the above answer (without select within a select) ?

Comment: @hosselausso That's easy. This offers no advantage over the other answer. To see why, follow these steps: 1. Add a PRIMARY KEY to booking(room_id,start). 2. Add a few dozen rows to each table. 3. Compare performance on both queries. 4. Run an EXPLAIN on both queries. I'm going to stick my neck out and say that a) my answer will take better advantage of indexes than the answer above, that b) fewer rows will be returned in the intermediate results, and that c) my query will perform (marginally) faster overall.

Comment: @Strawberry your answer was better than mine.  I posted my answer as you were posting yours.  I gave you a +1 as soon as I saw your post.